# Best Way to import Data Real time in C#

Tags: c#

I have a minor project that i've been working on for a while for an Independent study class. I am supposed to import around a 140,000 data points for a IDW based math analysis, currently it takes the program around 10~14 minutes to import all my points.

What I'm doing is reading off of a .txt file, splitting based on new line, and then splitting future based on spaces betweeen the fields. Then turning them into Datapt objects i designed for easy OOD style manipulation.

All i want to know is that I'll probably have to do a live demo with the program and i don't want people to have to sit there for 14 minutes while it preloads, if push comes to shove i could find a laptop from a friend (My main comp is a dekstop) and preload it on there before my presentation but the whole issue is making me wonder why is it taking so long to load only 100k datapts? I'd figure it would take a shorter amount of time? If there a quicker way than anyone knows of, it would be greatly appreciated if you could share it!

```
private void openPointsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files|*.txt|All files|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Open the Captured Packets";
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        //Check to see if a filename was given

        if (openFileDialog1.FileName != "")
        {
             readOut = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            //textBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            dataChain = readOut.Split(new String[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            //Read out Code
            string[] link; //dataChain[0].Split(null);



            for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                link = dataChain[i].Split(null);
                textBox1.AppendText(link[0] + "         " + link[1] + "         " + link[2] + "         "+ link[3] + "\r\n");
                dataPt Temp = new dataPt(Convert.ToDouble(link[0]), Convert.ToDouble(link[1]), Convert.ToDouble(link[2]), Convert.ToDouble(link[3]));

                dataList.Add(Temp);
                ptDisplay.Items.Add(Temp.ToString());

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is not efficient code, but ptDisplay looks like the killer to me.  Unclear what it is but just hide it since it doesn't do anything useful anyway while this code runs.  Or get rid of completely, nobody is going to look at a hundred thousand points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One improvement that comes to mind is that you don't need to load the whole file in memory. You can process it line by line using the [`ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) method which returns an `Enumerable<string>` on which you can further filter down the results using the `Take` extension method:

```
private void openPointsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files|*.txt|All files|*.*";
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Open the Captured Packets";
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

    if (openFileDialog1.FileName != "")
    {
        foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName).Take(100000))
        {
            var link = line.Split(null);
            textBox1.AppendText(link[0] + "         " + link[1] + "         " + link[2] + "         "+ link[3] + "\r\n");
            dataPt Temp = new dataPt(Convert.ToDouble(link[0]), Convert.ToDouble(link[1]), Convert.ToDouble(link[2]), Convert.ToDouble(link[3]));
            dataList.Add(Temp);
            ptDisplay.Items.Add(Temp.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right! I'm not used to working with forms so stripping the print statements and just printing the first and last item on the list to make sure everything made it seems to have worked flawlessly, Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Do not load the text all in memory at once. Instead use the File.ReadLines in your inner loop to enumerate the lines and process them one by one, but it is also very important to not change the TextBox.Text at each line. This is very expensive both in terms of execution and in terms of memory footprint. (Strings are immutable, so at each loop a new string is allocated in memory and the previous one is discarder wreaking havoc with memory fragmentation)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName))
{
    link = line.Split();
    sb.AppendLine(link[0] + "         " + link[1] + "         " + link[2] + "         "+ link[3]);
    dataPt Temp = new dataPt(Convert.ToDouble(link[0]), Convert.ToDouble(link[1]), Convert.ToDouble(link[2]), Convert.ToDouble(link[3]));
    dataList.Add(Temp);
    ptDisplay.Items.Add(Temp.ToString());
}
textBox1.AppendText(sb.ToString());
```

Instead add every line to a [StringBuilder class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) that handles a lot better the string concatenated together than a TextBox.Text property. Then when exiting the loop, change the TextBox.Text just one time.